# How to make divide number between 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays :

sales = [100, 125, 120] and
target = [100, 110, 115]

and I want to create new array ach which is sales/target so the array will be [1, 1.14, 1.04]

I still don't have any clue how to achieve it.
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you want to transform an array to another array with the same number of elements, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be your go to function. Note that function takes an index; you want to compare items of the same index in both arrays.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using a loop? It's trivial for someone to answer this question for you, but it doesn't look like you put any effort into it. You'll learn a lot more if you try something yourself, and then ask a specific question when you really get stuck.